# Photoshop multiple layers blending - save for web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, transparency, layout, blending

Through photoshop web template i found one interesting problem with multiple layers blending.

In the picture you can see screenshot of layout. Of course color is not part of it, just without color you could not see it.

Bottom part is how it looks default, before i marge all layers or save it for web (PNG 24, transparent). But when i save or marge, opacity settings for each layer change, so it looks terrible. (Upper part of screenshot)

I was looking for some decent solutions, but after hours still nothing...

[image]

Any help?

Comment: ... wait, how could you produce this *correct* image then? Flattening an image (either manually, or through Save For Web) should display exactly the same as when viewed "unmerged" in Photoshop.

Comment: Because this image is with BG in photoshop, but im saving it without BG. Then at the web site it looks like upper part.

Comment: Okay, there is your misconception then. Transparency is not a problem when you don't have a background; but all Photoshop effects **need** one. The effect does not get saved in a PNG – or in fact anywhere else than in a native PSD image. Scott's answer is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Blending modes **do not exist** outside of Photoshop. There's no way around that.

You will need to construct the image so that it does not rely on blending modes for its appearance.